# PHP: My text file only gets read when I add include function

Tags: php, file, file-handling

I am new to PHP and I am currently working on File Handling. I have a text file of which I am attempting to open for reading/appending using a skeleton script. The file is outputting and showing it is successfully opening, but only when I add a include function into the code. I have my code below, can someone look at it and tell me if I am doing it right because it feels right to me at the minute and it does output but i'm not 100% positive.

```
$location = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHPLabs/branches.txt';
include($location);

if (file_exists($location) && $file = fopen($location, 'r')){
    $file_content = fread($file, filesize($location));
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo 'File not found';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to read and output file to below:

```
$location = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHPLabs/branches.txt';
//include($location); remove include

if (file_exists($location) && $file = fopen($location, 'r')){
    $file_content = fread($file, filesize($location));
    echo $file_content; //<----echo here to display content
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo 'File not found';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use file_get_contents().
It will also read the text file but it will read the text files full contents to a string.

```
$location = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHPLabs/branches.txt';

if (file_exists($location)){
    $file_content = file_get_contents($file);
    Echo $file_content;
    $file_content .= " And some more"; //append string to end of string
    Echo $file_content; // echo with appended string.
    File_put_contetnts($file, $file_content); // save the original text plus the appended.
} else {
    echo 'File not found';
}
```